# -[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have this little problem I couldn't find in Google: 
`UITableView` works fine until I start scrolling.

```
Error Message: `-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector  sent to instance 0x5f24870 `
```

Method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];     
    if (cell == nil)
    { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }   
    // Set up the cell 
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length]-1];     
    //populate cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [[myArray objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"subject"]; 
    return cell;    
}
```

Just guessed that was the "problem"-method... if you need more infos: please tell me :)
thanks for all your help!

EDIT:
myArray is just the normal `NSArray *myArray`
It's a sorted Array ->

```
   NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lesson" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
myArray = [resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

resultArray (NSMutableArray) is the Result of an XML-Parser.. hope you can see my problem..

Comment: how you create myArray object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means that you're sending an `objectAtIndex:` messages to an object of type `NSString` (or possibly `CFString`). Of course you're expecting `myArray` to be an array and not a string.

What probably happened is that your array is being released (almost certainly autoreleased) too early and that by the time the method above is called the memory that *was* being pointed at by `myArray` now holds a string.

*In response to your edit...*

This line:

```
myArray = [resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

...is incorrect. The value is autoreleased. You need to retain it:

```
myArray = [[resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] retain];
```

Remember to release it before you close the view!

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly identified this method as the culprit I'm guessing this line is the problem:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[myArray objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"subject"];
```

To me it looks lime `myArray` is an instance of `NSCFString` and not a `NSArray`. You should start by double checking that and that you never assign anything but NSArray instances to `myArray`.

--edit--

Try

```
self.myArray = [resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

That should correctly retain the array for yoy to make sure it is not garbage collected and replaced with a rouge string :)

Answer (score 0):

myArray is proberbly autoreleased. Use self.myArray to set the sorted array. (with the correct @property (retain) )

Answer (score 0):

If myArray is an instance variable instead of a property, try:

```
myArray = [[resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] retain];
```