# Application (tableview) is crashing while scrolling

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview

I'm making an app which tries to read the information from the **.plist** file (put there parsed **JSON**).

The reading from file flows nice: got the array of dictionaries, but while trying to display it on tableview, the problems start. The initial view is loaded properly, but when I start scrolling, the app crashes.

```
#define DOCUMENTS [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    NSString *filePathDocArray = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filters.plist"];
    NSString *filePathBundleArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filters" ofType:@"plist"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePathDocArray]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:filePathBundleArray toPath:filePathDocArray error:nil];
        NSLog(@"File saved");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File already exists");
        filters = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePathDocArray];
    }

}
```

**Here I get all the info I need into filters array (checked by looping). Then:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [filters count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];                              
    }

    NSInteger crow = indexPath.row;
    NSDictionary *story = [filters objectAtIndex: crow];
    cell.textLabel.text = [story objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [story objectForKey:@"Description"];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

**When the app starts everething is OK: I see the normel table view, but when I start scrolling it crashes**

After series of breakpoint debugs I evaluated, that after the applications starts on Simulator, the link on array **filters** screws, so when I try to populate the next cell, the **story** dictionary can't be properly created.

What sort of problem it can be?

Here the console report:

> `2012-09-22 13:37:43.545 JSONExample[4559:207] -[__NSCFString
>   objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a083c0`
>
> `2012-09-22 13:37:43.547 JSONExample[4559:207] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',` `reason:
>   '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6a083c0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using ARC??
if not then autorelease the cell first!!
and if filters is not a retain property.. kindly make it one and synthesize it and again if ARC not used then release it in the dealloc block.. that should do it i suppose..

Comment: Thank you. Nope, I don't use ARC. what should I do to make filters retain properly?  I have     @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *filters; in header file. where should be autorelease added? Thank You again

Comment: Yes thats right retain and nonatomic in the header.. then synthesize it in the implementation file and you cell code should look like this..   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier]autorelease];

Answer (score 0):

[-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960351/nscfstring-objectatindex-unrecognized-selector) seems to be the same problem.

Your 'filters' variable is an NSString/CFString at the time you call `objectAtIndex:` - not an array, as you would assume. The solution given in the question linked to is to `retain` your filters array whenever it's set.

Comment: i set it   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *filters; in header file...what should I change? thanks

Comment: As stated in the question I linked to, you must `retain` your filters variable when you assign it. In this case, replace the line in `-viewDidLoad` with `filters = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePathDocArray] retain];`

Comment: Thank you! just added [[....] retain] to the 'filters = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePathDocArray];' so it became 'filters = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePathDocArray] retain];' and everything works properly!

Answer (score 0):

If you wote property for the `filters` like `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *filters;` you need to write like `self.filters = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePathDocArray];`

Else you need to write like `filters = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePathDocArray] retain];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind another thing..
if you do this step

```
 NSDictionary *story = [[filters objectAtIndex: crow]retain];
```

every time your cellForRowAtIndexPath is called the retain count would increase by 1. But you will delloc it only once.
So there will be memory leaks in your applications.
I suggest you go through the memory management guide once. its a small document. at max it will take one day of yours. But will feel more confident of what to do and what not to do.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.pdf

Cheers!! And Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thx! But I am retaining not the dictionary, but the array (filters) only once

Comment: Ok then.. it must not be of a gr8 concern then... Best luck and Happy coding!!